# API sending wrong data in body in Post using API call in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
 @override
  Future getPostApiSendNotificationResponse(String url, String token, String data) async {
    dynamic responseJson;
    Map<String, String>? header = {
      'Authorization': "Bearer $token"
    };
    Map data = {
      "deviceToken": token,
    };
    try {
      final response = await http
          .post(Uri.parse(url), body: data, headers: header)
          .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 10));
      responseJson = returnResponse(response);
    } on SocketException {
      throw FetchDataException("No Internet Connection");
    }
    return responseJson;
  }
```

above code is to send  data to server this post method sending device Token to server i am getting long character   from firebase as device token but when i send data to at ent its sending ... i dont know how i can send all character of device token  using post method in flutter .

[image]

Please help me in this issue i am new in flutter thanks

Comment: That's just `print` truncating the string as it is long - it's probably all being sent.

Comment: no in server its sending  getting asdasdsadas[] at end its coming array this is coming when i make map of data

Comment: can you try serializing the data? http.post body: json.encode(data)